# How to search a window name for an existence of an element of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very inexperienced with C++. I have a program that runs well. Part of the code relies on identifying some text in the name of a pop up window.

This is the partial part of code (which works fine)

```
    std::string firstNeedle("DX");
    std::size_t firstSearch = upperCaseWindowName.find(firstNeedle);
    std::string secondNeedle("BENJA");
    std::size_t secondSearch = upperCaseWindowName.find(secondNeedle);
    std::string thirdNeedle("BWB");
    std::size_t thirdSearch = upperCaseWindowName.find(thirdNeedle);
    std::string fourthNeedle("WDX");
    std::size_t fourthSearch = upperCaseWindowName.find(fourthNeedle);
    if ((firstSearch != std::string::npos) || (secondSearch != std::string::npos) || (thirdSearch != std::string::npos) || (fourthSearch != std::string::npos) ) {
```

I need to add quite a few more search terms and this method just isn't really sustainable.

I wondered if it's possible to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
string textToLookFor[] = { "DX", "BENJA", "BWB", "WDX", "FOO", "BAR" };
std::size_t searchingWindow = upperCaseWindowName.find(textToLookFor);
if ( (textToLookFor != std::string::npos) ){
```

Then I would simply add further terms to the array?

Comment: Why not just stuff that into a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it becomes slightly more sustainable if you rewrite it like this:

```
if (upperCaseWindowName.find("DX"   ) != std::string::npos ||
    upperCaseWindowName.find("BENJA") != std::string::npos ||
    ... )
```

Or you can use a `for` loop:

```
std::string patterns[] = {"DX", "BENJA", ...};
bool found = false;
for (const std::string &p : patterns)
{
    if (upperCaseWindowName.find(p) != std::string::npos)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {...}
```

Or `std::any_of`:

```
std::string patterns[] = {"DX", "BENJA", ...};
if (std::any_of(std::begin(patterns), std::end(patterns),
    [&](const std::string &p){return upperCaseWindowName.find(p) != std::string::npos;}))
{...}
```

Comment: a big thank you for your examples and help. Very much appreciated. I've accepted this as the answer as it covers everything I could need. Thanks again :-)